# How to change the stream in StreamProvider in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm consuming a stream from Firebase Firestore with a `StreamProvider` from the `provider`-package like the below code snippet shows (`DatabaseService.streamVehicles` is just a wrapper function to the actual query to Firestore).

In response to user events, the `locationId` variable will be set to different ids to filter in the Firestore query. However, whenever `locationId` changes, the component will rebuild, but the function passed to the `create`-parameter will not be called again, so the new value of `locationId` will not be passed to the query and the stream is still the same, unfiltered stream. How can I make sure a new stream is created whenever `locationId` changes?

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String id = 'home';

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final CupertinoTabController _tabController =
      CupertinoTabController(initialIndex: 0);

  String locationId;

  void setLocationId(String newId) {
    this.setState(() {
      locationId = newId;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Building homepage");
    return Consumer<User>(
      builder: (context, user, _) {
        return StreamProvider<List<Vehicle>>(
          create: (context) => DatabaseService.streamVehicles(
            user.organization.id,
            locationId: locationId,
          ),
          catchError: (ctx, err) {
            print("Error in stream");
            print(err);
            return [];
          },
          child: CupertinoTabScaffold(
            controller: _tabController,
            tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
              activeColor: kHighlightColor,
              items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.collections),
                  title: Text('Vehicles'),
                ),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.settings),
                  title: Text('Settings'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            tabBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              switch (index) {
                case 0:
                  return VehiclesPage(
                      locationId: locationId, setLocationId: setLocationId);
                case 1:
                  return SettingsPage();
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The `streamVehicles` method of `DatabaseService` is defined as the following.

```dart
  static Stream<List<Vehicle>> streamVehicles(
    String organizationId, {
    String locationId,
  }) {
    final Query ref = _firestore
        .collection('organizations')
        .document(organizationId)
        .collection('vehicles')
        .where(
          "location.id",
          isEqualTo: locationId,
        );

    return ref.snapshots().map((vehicleSnapshots) => vehicleSnapshots.documents
        .map((vehicleSnapshot) => Vehicle.fromFirestore(vehicleSnapshot))
        .toList());
  }
```

Comment: We have no way to know what `DatabaseService` looks like. Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because we shouldn't have to replicate both your database and your UI to help.

Comment: Yes, should've added immediately, added now @FrankvanPuffelen. I didn't think it would matter because the call to the function that returns the stream doesn't get called at all whenever `locationId` changes.

Comment: If it doesn't matter, you should be able to reproduce the problem without it. Ideally you want to share a single fragment of code that I can copy/paste into an existing project (as creating a new project takes time) and that will reproduce the problem. Requiring both a UI, and database typically precludes it from being one fragment, hence my question whether both are needed to answer your question. Note I don't doubt both are needed for your app, but the actual question you're asking usually requires only one or the other. E.g. database code with print statements is much easier to copy/paste.

Comment: Good point @FrankvanPuffelen, I'll definitely keep that in mind going forward. Thank you for bearing with me though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a new stream whenever something happens, and then render the contents of that stream, I'd typically store the stream in the state of the widget:

```
void setLocationId(String newId) {
  this.setState(() {
    locationId = newId;
  });
  // TODO: determine the new stream, and set that in the state too
}
```

Then in your `build` method, you use the stream from the state, instead of directly from the service.

Comment: Ahh, that's clever. But then you probably would have to use the `StreamProvider.value`-constructor instead of the regular `StreamProvider` for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Use a StreamProvider.family to create a new stream provider unique to each id's.

Comment: Thanks! I can't find that constructor in the StreamProvider docs, do you have a link to where I can read more about it?

Comment: Read http://riverpod.dev, and notice the description of ".family" as a modifier.  Then also note it is found on https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/all/StreamProvider-class.html.  Oh, it appears you are still using Provider package.  I don't think that was implemented for that.  Time to look at Riverpod. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll have a look at that!